# Only Managers/ bosses can view their sub ordinate in the hierarchy in the employee dashboard except some department employees. e.g. HR in Odoo

Tags: odoo, record-rules

This rule in the employee module works for the employee's(manager) respective own sub-hierarchy only.

```
[('id', 'child_of', [employee.id for employee in user.employee_ids ])]
```

But it also applies to all department employees e.g. HR.
While HR dep./users(employees) need to view all employees for their operations.
So have to overwrite the above rule or tweak the Above rule or any other method that works.

```
['|',('id', 'child_of', [employee.id for employee in user.employee_ids ]),('department_id', '!=', 3)]
```

I've applied the above but it shows HR(dep id = 3) all their sub-hierarchy, and not their dep employees because it covers in the first part but it shows other departments members all employees for which I initially applied this record rule.

Your Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your goal (For department!=3: Displaying flat hierarchy instead of vertical hierarchy?), it will solve your problem:

```py
['|',('id', 'child_of', [employee.id for employee in user.employee_ids ]),'&',('department_id', '!=', 3),('id', 'in', [employee.id for employee in user.employee_ids ])]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Odoo to apply record rules to a specific group of users and also empty domains against the other users so rule is not applied to other users.

the solution by @sylvain worked but for applying it and filtering but don't filter user groups so that this rule will not apply to the specific user's group.
following are the Steps I followed to solve this.

- I created a new user group as Hr_staff for the employee model.
- Go to the Employee record rule add the record rule and from below assign a group to this user e.g. Employee officer (maybe already checked)

  ['|',('id', 'child_of', [employee.id for employee in user.employee_ids ]),('user_id','=',user.id)]
- Go to the Employee record rule add the record rule and from below assign a group to this user as Hr_staff(can be any name).
  add an empty Domain as

  []

Hr_staff has to see all the employees.

the first rule will be applied to all users who are employee officers and can be set from users in settings.
the second rule will be applied to the Hr_staff (a newly created user group).

After applying this the HR staff can be able to see all employees. while the employee officer group or an employee that has sub employees can be able to see his sub employees and his own employee in view when he logged in and go to the employees' module.

Got help from this youtube video
[Youtube video link](https://youtu.be/p8gj1dEfYUM?t=982)